# Do not match Host * in ssh config if another rule was applied

Tags: ssh

I have the following SSH config:

```
Host work.github.com
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/work
    IdentitiesOnly yes

Host *
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/personal
```

Where I want to use a work SSH key for a single repository by setting it's host to `ssh://git@work.github.com:...`

But what I think is happening is that the work SSH key is applied and host changed, but then the config is re-parsed with `Host github.com` and `Host *` now matches and re-sets the SSH key to my personal one

Here is a snippet from `ssh -v git@work.github.com`

```
OpenSSH_8.8p1, OpenSSL 3.0.8 7 Feb 2023
debug1: Reading configuration data /var/home/me/.ssh/config
debug1: /var/home/me/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
// sets the correct SSH key
debug1: /var/home/me/.ssh/config line 4: Applying options for work.github.com
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config
debug1: configuration requests final Match pass
debug1: re-parsing configuration
debug1: Reading configuration data /var/home/me/.ssh/config
// Re-pases the file with Host: github.com and re-sets the SSH key
debug1: /var/home/me/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config
debug1: Connecting to github.com [140.82.121.4] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
...
Hi <PERSONAL>! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Connection to github.com closed.
Transferred: sent 2340, received 2404 bytes, in 0.4 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 5866.3, received 6026.7
debug1: Exit status 1
```

How can I handle this case?

Comment: Reverse the order of Host entries. The wildcard should go the last.

Comment: Edited, it seems to have started randomly working again, I am unsure why or what I did. (but previously it didn't work both at the top or bottom)

Comment: You can change wildcard to `Host * !work.github.com`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the "!" sign rule. For example:

```
Host work.github.com
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/work
    IdentitiesOnly yes

Host * !work.github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/personal
```